# Certain markup syntax breaking razor parsing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

The following snippet is breaking the razor parsing and the intellisense and U have no idea why isn't it working (yeah I did find a workaround, but it still bugs me).

```
<select class="form-control" @(ViewBag.View ? "disabled" : string.Empty) asp-for="repetitiveness" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TaskRepetitiveness>()">
    @if (ViewBag.View)
    {
        <option selected="selected" value="">@(EnumHelper<TaskRepetitiveness>.GetDisplayValue(Model.repetitiveness))</option>
    }
</select>
```

The disabled case is evaluating fine, yet the empty string case seems to be bugged (the below is the output after testing with browser):

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="repetitiveness" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TaskRepetitiveness>()"></select>
```

And here is intellisense breaking in action:

[image]
[image]
P.s. It still breaks with the braces for the tag helper:

[image]

Comment: the value of asp-items is not in brackets ... @(Html.GetEnumSelectList ...)

Comment: doesn't make a difference, still breaks any razor after it in the same element, here is another picture to prove it, also breaks the output aswell
https://imgur.com/TuJtzhE

Comment: Have you tried not using `string.Empty`?  Use `""` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is only valid within a tag when enclosed within quotes and assigned to an HTML attribute. In other words, something like the following should work:

```
<select  class="form-control" disabled="@(ViewBag.View as bool? ?? false)" asp-for="repetitiveness" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TaskRepetitiveness>()">
```

This may seem like it won't work because specifying `disabled` at all causes the field to be disabled, but Razor is smart enough to remove the attribute if it's false.

Comment: i was going to say html doesn't check for boolean attribute value, but you deserve a medal for this part "Razor is smart enough to remove the attribute if it's false."